# Simple Line Graph in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm having issues using the line chart control in SSRS. If I was in excel this would be easy but for some reason I can't wrap my head around how to do it in SSRS

I'm returning 5 rows of data from a database and need to chart 3 of the rows.

```
    Name             J  F   M   A   M   J   J   A   S
1   Requested        13 19  4   20  2   0   0   0   0   
2   Completed        1  0   0   4   1   0   0   0   0   
3   % Completed      .7 0   0   0.2 0.5 0   0   0   0
4   Monthly Ba       12 19  4   16  1   0   0   0   0   
5   YTD Backlog      12 31  35  51  52  52  52  52  52
```

The rows consist of the name and the value for that month.

I'm trying to display a chart for rows 1, 2, and 5 that would look like a normal line graph with each of the Months being on the horizontal column and the value being the data point.

However, when I start adding things to my chart I'm getting 36 different series, one for each Month for each series and nothing seems to be working right. It's also splitting into Group 1 and 2 at the bottom which makes no sense to me. I feel like I'm missing something simple, most likely a grouping of some kind.

EDIT:

I ended up taking Nathan's suggestion and added an unpivot on the table to rotate the data into an acceptable format for SSRS

Thanks

Comment: Assuming your data is coming from a SQLServer query, can you add the query to the question?

Comment: So the requests are held in `Table.Value` - are the Completed and YTD backlog fields held on the same table? If so, in what fields?

Comment: The Table columns are Value1, Value2, Value2 SubmittedMonth, Submitted Year.

The Table above is a Union of various different things to get that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you alter the query that is returning the results for the dataset?
If so try changing it so that the dataset looks more like this:

```
monthnumber month Requested Completed YTD Backlog
1           J     13        1         12
2           F     19        0         31
3           M     4         0         35
4           A     20        4         51
```

etc.

You should be able to add "Requested", "Completed" and "YTD Backlog" as Values and "month" as a Category to produce the chart you want.

I added a "monthnumber" column, as you will probably want something like this so that you can set the category (month) sorting expression to this, otherwise they will appear in alphabetical order.

Comment: So is the best option then to change the return format of the query then?